# open binance websocket and display price change not using specific library

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I think there is something I really didn't understand with Python Websockets.

And all I was able to read here is to switch to "unicorn binance" or similar.

My question is VERY simple : how to open a Binance websocket **without using a third party library** and to see the prices of BTC EUR (as an example, I will figure out for any other pair) arriving ???

Because this doesn't work.

```
import websocket
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/BTCEUR')
ws.run_forever()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Binance has it own protocol implemented around WS. You can implement it according to [the documentation.](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#individual-symbol-mini-ticker-stream).
If you don't want to use 3rd parties, read their code and adjust it to your needs.
A good example (asyncio) is [here](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/00dc9a978590e79d4aa02e6c75106a3632990e8d/binance/websockets.py#L10).